# How to use operators defined in namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces, operators, literals

I have an operator defined in a namespace as follows:

```cpp
namespace Foo {
  class Bar {
    public:
      Bar(double val): baz(val) {}
    // Rest of my object here

    private:
      double baz;

  };

  namespace Qux {
    Bar operator ""
    _quux(long double opd) {
      return Bar(opd / 10);
    }
  }
}



int main() {
  using namespace Foo::Qux;
  std::cout << "100_quux" << std::endl;

}
```

How do I use the operator without introducing the `Foo::Qux` namespace into my `main()` scope?

Comment: I thought about using ```Foo::Qux::operator_quux (100)``` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I would suggest you to get the operator working without namespaces first, because the namespace isnt the major problem in your code. Also there is no `operator<<` for `Bar`

Comment: I've never seen `operator ""` in the wild before. Saw it had been added in C++11, but never looked into it. Now that I have, that's a <expletive deleted> to find documentation on. cppreference doesn't even seem to cover it.

Comment: The fully qualified name of the operator is `Foo::Qux::operator""_quux`, not `Foo::Qux::operator_quux`. You can invoke it with that, or you can also do `using Foo::Qux::operator""_quux;` to use the literal operator without `using` the rest of the namespace.

Comment: @user4581301 cppreference has it under [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Comment: Holy cow. I've used those and never drawn the connection. Crom, I've answered questions here on user defined literals and never drew the connection. This is like the time I couldn't find a flash light for months because it'd been moved two feet to the right to the other side of the toaster. Excuse me while I head off and feel incredibly stupid for a while.

Comment: Here's a good page about [user defined literals : operator" "](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/user-defined-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't qualify the namespace for user define literals like

```
std::cout << 100.0Foo::Qux::_quux << std::endl
```

But what you can do is use a using statement to import just the literal operator into `main` using

```
using Foo::Qux::operator""_quux;
```

and you would use it like

```
std::cout << 100.0_quux << std::endl;
```

You could also call the operator manually like

```
std::cout << Foo::Qux::operator""_quux(100.) << std::endl;
```

---

Another option would be to place your user define literals into a namespace called `literals` and then you can just import that into main.  That would look like

```
namespace Foo {
  class Bar {
    public:
      Bar(double val): baz(val) {}
    // Rest of my object here

    private:
      double baz;

  };

  namespace Qux {
    inline namespace literals {
      Bar operator ""_quux(long double opd) {
        return Bar(opd / 10);
      }
    }
    // other Qux Members
  }
}



int main() {
  using namespace Foo::Qux::literals;
  std::cout << 100.0_quux << std::endl;

}
```

Note that literals is an inline namespace so that `Qux` can still access the members without additional qualification.

Comment: Since `Foo::Qux` only contains the literal it already serves the purpose of separating the literals from the rest. It could be renamed into `literals` though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That was my though, but the last sentence in the Q makes me think that `Qux` has other members that just aren't shown here.

Comment: I've accepted your answer(thanks!) - can you also add @NathanPierson's comment into it for completeness?

Comment: @cshastry You're welcome.  I've also added in the manual call version.